# Find range of dates within same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a data set, which looks like this:

```
ResourceID           RequirementId        ProjectID            Startdate               EndDate                 BillingPercentage
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
1                    5066                 7505                 2015-09-15 00:00:00.000 2015-09-30 00:00:00.000 50
2                    4748                 7499                 2015-09-10 00:00:00.000 2015-09-20 00:00:00.000 50
```

I want to calculate range and corresponding billing % for that particular month my query is:

```
    INSERT INTO @DateTimeline
    SELECT @MonthStartDate AS OSTARTDATE,@MonthEndDate AS OENDDATE,0 

    INSERT INTO @DateTimeline
    SELECT Startdate AS OSTARTDATE,EndDate AS OENDDATE,BillingPercentage From @RESOURCE_UNBILLED Order by Startdate

    INSERT INTO @DateTimeline
    SELECT EndDate AS OSTARTDATE,EndDate AS OENDDATE,BillingPercentage From  @RESOURCE_UNBILLED Order by Startdate
```

And data looks like following:

```
 SerialNo    OSTARTDATE              OENDDATE                BillingPercentage
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           2015-09-01 00:00:00.000 2015-09-30 00:00:00.000          0
2           2015-09-10 00:00:00.000 2015-09-20 00:00:00.000         50
3           2015-09-15 00:00:00.000 2015-09-30 00:00:00.000         50
4           2015-09-20 00:00:00.000 2015-09-20 00:00:00.000         50
5           2015-09-30 00:00:00.000 2015-09-30 00:00:00.000         50
```

I want to retrive data like following

```
    OSTARTDATE              OENDDATE                BillingPercentage
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
2015-09-01 00:00:00.000 2015-09-10 00:00:00.000               0
2015-09-10 00:00:00.000 2015-09-15 00:00:00.000              50
2015-09-15 00:00:00.000 2015-09-20 00:00:00.000             100
2015-09-20 00:00:00.000 2015-09-30 00:00:00.000              50
```

Please suggest how can I get this also can I use pivot here?

Comment: Its a little hard to understand your expected outputs are coming from. What data is @RESOURCE_UNBILLED in your calculation querys? In your final table where are your start and end date ranges coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Use a table variable to store your `@dateStamps` with columns: `SerialNo`, `OSTARTDATE` and `OENDDATE`.

Try this query:

```
SELECT  d.SerialNo, d.OSTARTDATE, d.OENDDATE
        , ( SELECT SUM(t.BillingPercentage)
            FROM yourTable t
            WHERE d.OENDDATE BETWEEN t.Startdate AND t.EndDate
               OR d.OSTARTDATE BETWEEN t.Startdate AND t.EndDate
               OR (d.OSTARTDATE > t.Startdate AND d.OENDDATE < t.EndDate)
              ) AS BillingPercentage
FROM 
    @dateStamps d
```

---

My complete code is:

```
DECLARE @DatePart as int = 5

;WITH dateStamps AS (
    SELECT 1 As SerialNo, CAST('2015-' + CONVERT(varchar, MONTH(MIN(t.Startdate))) + '-01 00:00:00.000' As datetime) AS OSTARTDATE
                        , CAST('2015-' + CONVERT(varchar, MONTH(MIN(t.Startdate))) + '-01 00:00:00.000' As datetime) + (@DatePart - 1) AS OENDDATE

    FROM yourTable t
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ds.SerialNo + 1, ds.OSTARTDATE + @DatePart, ds.OSTARTDATE + (@DatePart * 2 - 1)
    FROM dateStamps ds
    WHERE MONTH(OSTARTDATE + @DatePart) <= MONTH(ds.OSTARTDATE)
)
SELECT  d.SerialNo, d.OSTARTDATE, d.OENDDATE
        , ( SELECT SUM(t.BillingPercentage)
            FROM t
            WHERE d.OENDDATE BETWEEN t.Startdate AND t.EndDate
               OR d.OSTARTDATE BETWEEN t.Startdate AND t.EndDate
               OR (d.OSTARTDATE > t.Startdate AND d.OENDDATE < t.EndDate)
              ) AS BillingPercentage
FROM 
    dateStamps d
```